# adding a complex animation without using UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

i want to create a childrens book like this one:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sc1APRfP2o8

and i wanted to know, How do i create the animations? I have searched and all i can find are creating animations via putting together UIImages and then playing them. But i sure hope i do not have to do this with my whole book. I was wondering if there is another program i could use to create the animation in and then import it into Xcode and then just call it to play. Is this possible? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't watch the video but if you want to create an animation easily aybe you can try gif

```
NSData *gif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: 
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"gif"]]; 

UIWebView *view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
[view loadData:gif MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

this might work

Comment: could this allow me to import a video, or an animation and play it? And thanks for the reply!!

Comment: no, if you want to play video then you can try MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: okay, i can try this too! but is it possible just to import an animation and then play that? Thanks!

Comment: what's the format of your "animation"?
video? gif? list of Image? or something else?

Comment: if you just use png files,then
[UIImage animatedImageWithImages:(NSArray *)images duration:            (NSTimeInterval)duration]
this should work

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Cocoas2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org).

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have found a few animation tuts, but none of animations being imported into xcode. Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: how do you mean imported in xcode? XCode is not going to give you frame by frame animation GUI like Flash.

Comment: i mean if i create an animation, could i just import that animation into xcode. Kinda of like if i imported an image or a sound. So, i would have to create an entire children's book by playing a set of images. Doesnt that seem a bit ridiculous?

Comment: also, im not asking if i can create an animation in xcode, im asking if i can create one in another program, then just import it into xcode!!